# ES6 JavaScript classes

Tags: javascript, class, oop, ecmascript-6

Is there a way to create a class and in that classes constructor method pass in two different objects from other classes, along with some other information. For example, say I have three classes, a Statistics class, an Attributes class, and a Character class. They look kind of like this:

```
class Statistics {
    constructor(stren, dex, wis, cha, armorClass, hitPoints) {
        this._stren = stren;
        this._dex = dex;
        this._wis = wis;
        this._cha = cha;
        this._armorClass = armorClass;
        this._hitPoints = hitPoints;
    }
}

class Attributes {
    constructor(name, race, sex, level, height, weight, speed) {
        this._name = name;
        this._race = race;
        this._sex = sex;
        this._level = level;
        this._height = height;
        this._weight = weight;
        this._speed = speed;
    }
}
```

Since the Character class' constructor would have 13+ arguments, I figured separating them into other classes was better than writing a constructor with 13+ arguments. So is there a way to do something similar to:

```
class Character {
    constructor(Statistics statistic, Attributes attributes) {
        .....
    }
}
```

EDIT: No, this is not a duplicate of that question, do people even actually read what is being asked before saying that questions are duplicates?

Comment: yes and no ... `constructor(statistic, attributes)` - and check that the two arguments are of the right class in the constructor

Comment: Is there anything wrong with passing these new objects into the `Character` class as arguments? Just as generic arguments with no "typechecking".

Comment: Do you want the `Character` to get all the properties from statistics/attributes?  If so here's a fiddle showing how to do that https://jsfiddle.net/fhnqh2og/

Comment: I think you just described Typescript.

Comment: the main idea is that the Statistics class will have getter methods (such as get dex() { return this._dex; } and I want to be able to store all the information into one object, but still be able to access the dex information with the getter method

Comment: @Mike You can still do that still do that. It's a little more involved, though. I can show you, if you'd like.

Comment: @Andrew Sure, that would be great. I did just throw the two objects into a created Character object and that works, but then when I go (lets say I went newCharacter = new Character(attributes, statistics) ) console.log(newCharacter.dex) it returns undefined

Comment: @Mike I have the answer for you, but I cannot post it, as this question is marked as a duplicate. It technically is, based on your question. Make a new post with the question: 'Making a custom getter with ES6 classes'. That shouldn't be marked as a duplicate and I can directly answer this question. Link it here in the comments.

Comment: @Andrew question re-opened. Post your answer :)

Comment: @Mike you need to be clearer when asking questions

Comment: @Mike I still have no idea what you are asking for. Yes, of course a constructor can have two parameters that get passed other objects. What exactly is the problem? How is the `.....` in the `Character` constructor supposed to look?

Comment: @Bergi The combination of Andrew's answer and your comment answered the question. The .... in the Character constructor is completely irrelavant, as the issue was figuring out how to pass the two objects into that constructor and still have access to any getter methods that I might need to put into the other two classes without having to keep around a variables for statistics and attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remember that classes are just syntactic sugar, so you can add to the `Character` prototype with `Object.defineProperty` and make your own getter.

edit: DRYd it up with a loop.

```js
class Statistics {
    constructor(stren, dex, wis, cha, armorClass, hitPoints) {
        this._stren = stren;
        this._dex = dex;
        this._wis = wis;
        this._cha = cha;
        this._armorClass = armorClass;
        this._hitPoints = hitPoints;
    }
}

class Attributes {
    constructor(name, race, sex, level, height, weight, speed) {
        this._name = name;
        this._race = race;
        this._sex = sex;
        this._level = level;
        this._height = height;
        this._weight = weight;
        this._speed = speed;
    }
}

class Character {
    constructor(statistics, attributes) {
        this.buildGetters(attributes)
        this.buildGetters(statistics)
      }
      
      buildGetters(obj) {
        for (let attr in obj){
          Object.defineProperty(Character.prototype, attr.replace("_", ""), {
            get: function() {
              return obj[attr]
            }
          })
        }
      }
}


const stats = new Statistics()
const attr = new Attributes("Mike")
const mike = new Character(stats, attr)
console.log(mike.name);
```

Comment: why would you not just write `get name() { return this._attributes._name }` in the `Character` class body? `Object.defineProperty` would only be necessary if you wanted to dynamically create properties with different names

Comment: Can you show me the documentation for this? I know `get` works with ES5 constructors but I was under the impression that it doesn't work with the class syntax.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! That is what I am after, I do agree that doing that 13 times would be rather... time consuming and take up a lot of space. Any suggestions on how to do that in a better way?

Comment: @Andrew [`get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) works in ES5 object literals and ES6 classes.

Comment: @Mike Just `Object.defineProperty` them in a loop over the property name strings.

Comment: @Bergi Thank you! Using the getter function directly in the Character class would work, I just didn't realize you could go quite that direct of an approach. It will still be not fun doing that for all the attributes, but it does give me the desired result and doesn't look too nasty either!

Comment: @Bergi If you want internet points, go ahead and write that as your own answer. If not, I can change mine.

Comment: @Mike PS: Please upvote and mark as the correct answer. This was a lot of work LOL.